# Ubuntu 20.10 network crashing

Tags: networking, ethernet, crash, raspberrypi, firmware

After upgrading ubuntu 20.10 from 20.4.1 my network is no longer stable.
It works for a day or two and then just stops responding until I shut it down and start again.
Nothing is possible to do once it stops (no pinging, no response...) Just nothing.
What is possible to do or check in order to eliminate the problem ?
My HW is RPi-4 8GB with latest HW firmware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem on **ubuntu/linux** with **IPV6 disable** actions.
It looks like that was actually the main cause in my case. 
But I'm not entirely sure if the problem is **UBUNTU latest version (20.10)** or 
the **RPi-4 8GB** latest firmware updates.
My problems started after latest updates. Everything worked well on 
**UBUNTU version (20.04)** for last 6 months... 
Anyway, hope this can help someone....facing the same problems as I did...

As I have seen discussions from the past...This "bug" was also noticed in 
 the past with UBUNTU/linux.., so maybe someone can take a closer look to this issue.