# Ubuntu 20.10 degrading network latency

Tags: networking, 20.10

I'm running Ubuntu 20.10 and after a while my network latency rises

This happens even to LAN addresses, for example here's me pinging a computer on the same network. Normally the ping is ~5ms, but eventually it goes to about 500ms

[image]

I believe this is an Ubuntu issue because it's fixed by disconnecting/reconnecting to the network from my computer

Any tips? I found this similar post: [Ubuntu 20.10 network crashing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1307997/ubuntu-20-10-network-crashing) but I don't want to disable IPv6... and if this issue is widespread it seems strange to me that it hasn't been addressed.

## Network Info

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 20
       serial: 18:cc:18:9d:47:ca
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.11.0-7614-generic firmware=59.601f3a66.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-59.u ip=10.0.0.110 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:80884000-80887fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:24:00.0
       logical name: enp36s0
       version: 15
       serial: 80:fa:5b:93:ae:56
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.11.0-7614-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:17 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:80604000-80604fff memory:80600000-80603fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: virbr0-nic
       serial: 52:54:00:11:bf:18
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
```

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
```

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

```
iwconfig
```

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp36s0   no wireless extensions.

wlp0s20f3  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"..."  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.2 GHz  Access Point: ...   
          Bit Rate=195.1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=45/70  Signal level=-65 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:731   Missed beacon:0

virbr0    no wireless extensions.

virbr0-nic  no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.
```

```
iwlist wlp0s20f3 freq
```

```
wlp0s20f3  32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Current Frequency:5.2 GHz (Channel 40)
```

Comment: Do you use a wired, or wireless connection? Please describe your physical network configuration. Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks, I put the outputs in the question. `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` didn't return anything

Comment: Edit your question and show me `iwconfig` and `iwlist wlp0s20f3 freq`. What make/model router? Can you install `WiFi Analyzer` on your smart phone?

Comment: @heynnema updated! And sure re:WiFi Analyzer, but the latency issue seems to only occur on this laptop. Other devices in the house don't appear to have a slow down (if you're thinking about interfering bands from other routers). p.s. these commands are really useful, learning a lot here

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to you... I went on a mini-vacation... just got back. You're using a low channel in the 5Ghz band... higher channels work better. Is the 5Ghz channel set to AUTO or channel 40 in your router? If it's hardwired, change it to another higher channel that `Wifi Analyzer` doesn't show as being in use. Report back.